# Using an input field containing a RegEx and Jquery to validate a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms

I'm attempting to have Jquery validate a form using regular expression, but in an unconventional way. The form id is "sumform" and a textarea within the form is called "summary." I have another input field (id="terms_out") outside of the form which contains the regular expression. I can't seem to get the Jquery validator to recognize the value of "terms_out" as a regex. My form ends up being submitted when the user enters anything.

I've tried this but it doesn't work...

```
$(function() {
   $.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexpr) {  
   return regexpr.test(value); 
   }, "Sorry, you haven't used all the terms.");    

   $("#sumform").validate({
   rules: {
       summary: {
           required: true,
           regex: '#terms_out',
       }
     }
  });
});
```

This works perfectly fine...

```
$(function() {
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
 return regexpr.test(value);
}, "Sorry, you haven't used all the terms.");    

   $("#myForm").validate({
       rules: {
           experience: {
               required: true,
               regex: /^(?=[\S\s]*\bcell|cells|cell\b)(?=[\S\s]*\bDNA|DNA|DNA\b)(?=[\S\s]*\bsense|senses|sense\b)(?=[\S\s]*\brespond|responds|respond\b)(?=[\S\s]*\benergy|energy|energy\b)(?=[\S\s]*\bgrow|grows|grow\b)(?=[\S\s]*\bdevelop|develops|develop\b)(?=[\S\s]*\breproduce|reproduces|reproduce\b)/
           }
       }
   });
});
```

I'm very new at this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch:

`regex: '#terms_out',`

to:

`regex: $("#terms_out").val(),`

EDIT:

```
 $("#Form").validate({
       rules: {
           summary: {
               required: true,
              regex: new RegExp($("#terms_out").val())
           } 
       }
   });
```

That will take the value from the text area and insert it to ruls

Comment: Thanks for your help Saar, but that doesn't seem to work. Here's the link to my summary form http://wisscience7-lessons.weebly.com/summary-2-1.html -  The "terms_out" field is in the upper left-hand corner.

Comment: Hi, I debugged your code and the problem is that your validate function is being called before you added the regular expression to your `terms_out` make sure your code runs in correct order

Comment: Thanks again Saar for your help. I'm sorry, but how do you know the validate function is being called before the regex is available? I've successfully used this method before, except it was just a simple numerical value that was going to the input field. Again, thank you.

Comment: @firenemus it's easy, I debugged the code, put a break point in your validate function and saw that at that time your input field is still empty. an easy way to check this is just in the same on ready function before calling the validate function add a line that sets the value inside of the input field and you will see that it works

Comment: Thanks for explaining Saar. Yes, it takes a moment for the google visualization api query to retrieve the regex, but I don't believe that's why the validation is failing. I think it has something to do with the Jquery validator not being able to recognize the regex inside the input field. For example, if I assign a value to the input field without doing a query it still doesn't work. See here for example...  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbVmvZ?editors=101

Comment: Hi @firenemus, now I debugged it and saw the other problem, see my edit

Comment: @ saar Hello again! We're getting closer, but something is still not right. Now instead of submitting when any character is entered, the key terms in the regex are not being recognized and the form won't submit at all. I know the regex itself works. For instance, if I type "cell" or "cells" into the summary input field and click submit it I'm getting the fail message "wrong terms." Please see... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbVmvZ?editors=101 Thanks again for all your time and help with this.

Comment: found what is the issue, you need to remove the first `/` and the last `/` from the string